# Cannot Get DLookup Function to work in Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I am trying to get the Dlookup function to work in Access 2013, but i just cannot get it to work, heres what i have so far :-

I have a query called `qry_VehicleOverview` in this query there are Two fields called `VehicleNumber` and `DateLastExam`

I have a form, there are a number of fields, two of them called `Vehicle1` and `DateLastExamV1`, in `DateLastExam1` ! am trying to reference the relevant exam based on `Vehicle1` from `qry_VehicleOverview` field, so when a Vehicle Number is added to `Vehicle1` it displays the correct Exam in `DateLastExam1`

first of all I create a combo box in the form, called `Vehicle1` and referenced it to `VehicleNumber` from `qry_VehicleOverview`

then i created a text box in the form, and called it `LastExamVehicle1`, in the control source of this field I added the DLookup function :-

`=DLookup("[DateLastExam]","qry_VehicleOverview","[VehicleNumber]=""" & [Vehicle1].[Text] & """")`

Then chose `After update` in `Event` tab and Selected `code Builder` in here I added :-

`Private Sub LastExamVehicle1_AfterUpdate()
     Me.LastExamVehicle1.Requery
 End Sub`

but when run the form, first of all i get an error of #Type in the field, when i change the value in `Vehicle1` the eror then changes to #Error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I create a combo box in the form, called Vehicle1 and referenced it to
>   VehicleNumber from qry_VehicleOverview

If that is so, there is no need for DLookup as you already have the value.

Set the *RowSource* of Vehicle1 to *qry_VehicleOverview* and the count of fields for the combobox to 2 and use this *ControlSource* for your textbox:

```
=[Vehicle1].[Column](1)
```

It will automatically update.

Comment: Thanks for the help, however I don't see `count of fields`, is this `column count`

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly, one more question, if you can help, how do I store that value `LastExamV1` from the form in a table?

Comment: You can either open the table as a _DAO.Recordset_ and call the _.AddNew_ and _.Update_ methods (normally the fastest and cleanest), or call _CurrentDb.Execute_ to run an _SQL insert query_.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `[Vehicle1].[Text]`, use `[Vehicle1].[Value]` instead. Or just `[Vehicle1]` .
(`.Value` is the default property)

`.Text` is only valid while the focus is in the control, and in `AfterUpdate` it isn't anymore.

`.Text` is mainly useful in the `Change` event, but that wouldn't make sense for your case.

**Edit**

You probably need the "full path" to the control in `DLookup`. For better readability I suggest using single quotes.

```
=DLookup("[DateLastExam]","qry_VehicleOverview","[VehicleNumber]='" & Forms!yourForm![Vehicle1] & "'")
```

Also please double-check all names in your form (and then in your question). E.g. from your description, your event procedure should read:

```
Private Sub Vehicle1_AfterUpdate()
     Me.DateLastExamV1.Requery
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, i have removed the [Text], but still get the #Error

Comment: Hi, i have edited my question to display the correct field name, also i have tried your suggestion but still cannot get it to work, here is me DLookup `=DLookUp("[DateLastExam]","qry_VehicleOverview","[VehicleNumber]='" & [Forms]![frm_McuTrackerList]![Vehicle1] & "'")`